# Linking QLineEdit's "enter" event to a slot?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

I do have the following code:

```
def init_widgets(self):
        mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel("Enter a song name: ")
        self.search_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.search_button = QtGui.QPushButton("&Search") # QCommandLinkButton
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.search_slot)
        self.table = self.createTable()
        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel("iQuality v1.00 by Itay Brandes")

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.search_lineEdit, 0, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.search_button, 0, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0, 1, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label2, 2, 0)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

How can I run `self.search_slot` if the user presses the enter button on `self.search_lineEdit`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`QLineEdit` has a [`returnPressed`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#returnPressed) signal. You can connect that signal from `search_lineEdit` to your custom slot.

Not familiar with the PyQt syntax, but should be something like:

```
 self.search_lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.search_slot)
```